# Coding the remove() method in ListIterator

Tags: java

I am creating a double-linked list (has a previous and next pointer) from scratch using nodes. I'm trying to write the methods to implement a ListIterator and I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the remove method.  I know it is probably something really simple but I don't have a lot of experience with iterators and I can't find a tutorial or post on this anywhere.

```
    private Node<E> cur;
    private Node<E> head;

        public E next() {
        if(size == 0) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        if(cur.next == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return cur.next.value;
    }

        public boolean hasNext() {
        boolean flag = cur != null;
        return flag;
    }

        public void remove() {
        //??????????????????
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a node, the `prev` node needs to point to `next` node, and vice versa (respective to `current`) . That's it. Pretty simple.

Edge cases to consider:

- Deleting head node
- Deleting tail node
- Deleting last remaining node

I hope this is enough for you to code it yourself.